# How to change IOptions during runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, consul

I keep information about my services (host, name) in appsettings. Sometimes I want to retrieve info about host not from appsettings but from [Consul](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul). So I want to configure `IOptions` in runtime, check if Host is presented and if not I want to query Consul to get it.

My options in `appsettings.json` look like this:

```json
"MyServices": {
  "MyServiceA": {
    "ServiceName": "ServiceAName",
    "ConsulDataCenter": "",
    "Host": "http://localhost:12345"
  },
 "MyServiceB": {
    "ServiceName": "ServiceBName",
    "ConsulDataCenter": ""
  }
}
```

So `ServiceA` host should be taken from appsettings and `ServiceB` host should be taken from Consul. First, I created a class representing my options:

```
public class MyServicesOptions : Dictionary<string, ConsulServiceData> { }

public sealed class ConsulServiceData
{
    public required string ServiceName { get; init; }
    public required string ConsulDataCenter { get; init; }
    public string Host { get => _uri?.Host; set => _uri = new Uri(value); }
    public Uri Uri { get => _uri; }
    private Uri _uri;
}
```

Next, I need to configure `IOptions`. I've created an interface:

```
public interface IConfigureOptionsAsync<in TOptions> where TOptions : class
{
    Task ConfigureAsync(TOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

and a class which implements the above described logic of configuration:

```
 public class ConfigureServicesAsync : IConfigureOptionsAsync<MyServicesOptions>
 {
     protected readonly ConsulService _consulService;
     private readonly ILogger<ConfigureMyServicesAsync> _logger;

     public ConfigureMyServicesAsync(ConsulService consulService, ILogger<ConfigureMyServicesAsync> logger)
     {
         _consulService = consulService;
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public virtual async Task ConfigureAsync(MyServicesOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         try
         {
             foreach (var (clientName, client) in options)
             {
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.Host))
                 {
                     var result = await _consulService.GetServiceUriAsync(client.ServiceName, null, new QueryOptions { Datacenter = client.ConsulDataCenter }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                     if (result is null)
                     {
                         _logger.LogWarning("Could not retrieve address from consul for service {serviceName}. Reason: {error}", client.ServiceName, result.Error);
                         continue;
                     }
                     client.Host = result;
                 }
                 _logger.LogInformation("Address for {serviceName} - {uri}", client.ServiceName, client.Uri);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while configuring rest consul services: {exception}", ex.Message);
             throw;
         }
     }
 }
```

Then create hosted service for asynchronous configuration:

```
public class ConfigureOptionsHostedService<TOptions> : IHostedService where TOptions : class
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public ConfigureOptionsHostedService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var scope = _services.CreateScope();
        var configurator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfigureOptionsAsync<TOptions>>();
        var options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>>();
        await configurator.ConfigureAsync(options.CurrentValue, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Create methods to hosted service for options configuration

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureOptionsAsync<TOptions, TConfigureOptionsAsync>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TConfigureOptionsAsync : class, IConfigureOptionsAsync<TOptions>
    where TOptions : class
{
    services.AddHostedService<ConfigureOptionsHostedService<TOptions>>();
    services.AddScoped<IConfigureOptionsAsync<TOptions>, TConfigureOptionsAsync>();
    return services;
}
```

and register all the stuff

```
public static void AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.Configure<MyServicesOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyServices"));
    services.ConfigureOptionsAsync<MyServicesOptions, ConfigureMyServicesAsync>();
}
```

Finally, I want to obtain address for my `HttpClient` from `IOptions`.

```
 services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceA, MyServiceA>((sp, client) =>
 {
     var uri = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyServicesOptions>>().Value.GetValueOrDefault("ServiceA")?.Uri;
    
     client.BaseAddress = uri;
 });

services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceB, MyServiceB>((sp, client) =>
{
    var uri = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyServicesOptions>>().Value.GetValueOrDefault("ServiceB")?.Uri;
    
    client.BaseAddress = uri;
});
```

And here is the question. `HttpClient` for `ServiceA`, which address was specified in `appsettings.json`, is obtained correctly. But `ServiceB` address is `null`. I thought that query to Consul returns null (line from `ConfigureServicesAsync`)

```
var result = await _consulService.GetServiceUriAsync(client.ServiceName, null, new QueryOptions { Datacenter = client.ConsulDataCenter }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

but its not the case, the address is correctly obtained from Consul and assign it to `Host` in options.

So what am I doing wrong? Why my `IOptions` configuration does not work even if I receeve correct address from Consul and assign it correctly?

Comment: What is "Consul"? Do you mean "Console"? And are you aware of [IOptionsMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#ioptionsmonitor) ?

Comment: @Fildor Consul is [Consul from HashiCorp](https://www.consul.io/). I read about `IOptionsMonitor`, but I don't understand why I should use it because I don't change my `appsettings.json` itself, I only change `IOptions` (which are singleton and I guess direct changing of them should work).

Comment: Ah, ok. I was really confused. Maybe you should [edit] the question and add that reference to HashiCorp/Consul...

Comment: Idk why but replacing `IOptions<MyServicesOptions>` with `IOptionsMonitor<MyServicesOptions>` in `services.AddHttpClient` works. Guess I should investigate how options work in ASP .NET Core... You can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I would, but I was right for the wrong reasons. Maybe write an answer as soon as you found out why that works. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

IOptions is singleton service that reads the configuration value from the configuration source when the app starts, and remains unchanged throughout the app's lifecycle. If you change the data in the configuration source at runtime, IOptions does not automatically update these values.IOptionsMonitor is also a singleton service, but it is able to respond to configuration changes. 'IOptionsMonitor' dynamically updates the configuration value when the configuration changes and can provide the most up-to-date configuration data for each request.

In your case MyServicesOptions is configured to fetch values dynamically from appsettings.json and Consul. When you use 'IOptions', ServiceA's address is correctly obtained because it is already defined in 'appsettings.json' when the app starts. However, ServiceB's address is obtained from Consul at runtime, which is why you need to use 'IOptionsMonitor'.

When you use IOptionsMonitor, the service dynamically queries Consul at runtime, and when the configuration returned from Consul is updated, it is able to catch those changes and update the configuration values internally. This the reason why replacing 'IOptions' with 'IOptionsMonitor' works for you.

Here is the official document you can refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#options-interfaces